# airflow dag problem in run - run schedule in loop

Tags: airflow, schedule, airflow-scheduler

i create this dag for run command on remote ssh in schedule.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook as sscon
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
    'email': ['e@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    #'retries': 1,
    #'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
}
dag = DAG(
    'ssh_second',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple bash DAG LAB',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=1),
    tags=['test'],
)

sshcon = sscon(remote_host="192.168.1.250", username="user", password="password", port=22)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='echo1',
    bash_command='echo "simple task! by dag" ',
    dag=dag,
)

t5 = SSHOperator(
    task_id="remote-connection",
    command="/bin/date >> /home/user/date.txt && echo 'from airflow' >> /home/user/date.txt",
    ssh_hook=sshcon,
    dag=dag)

t1 >> t5
```

and its worked but airflow run it in every second and unstoppable.

[tree view of loop run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vses.png)

i do not know where the problem comes from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `schedule_interval` is set for every minute: `schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=1)` which is what's causing the DAG to execute so frequently.  Update the `schedule_interval` to an interval that is less frequent.

Also, I would *highly* recommend modifying the `start_date` to a static value rather than a dynamic one (e.g. `days_ago(0)`). This [guide](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dag-best-practices), and others, were really useful when I started with Airflow. Once you set a static `start_date` you can set `catchup=False` if you do not want the DAG to execute "missing" runs from the `start_date` to present time.

Comment: Please guide me how can I run a dag every 1 minute?

Comment: @EhsanGholami You're doing it now in your code when you create the `DAG` object: `schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=1)`.